# Cannot close facebook invite popup when click cancel button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have created facebook application and it also have invite friends functionality.
I ve created inivite popup of facebook . This reffered from following link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

My problem is when I click the cancel button popup page redirect to [another url](https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#cb=f40ba6e94&origin=http://lms.linkmusicservices.com/f2f685cad&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f18ce141f8&result=null).
So I cant remove popup from page.
How can remove this popup directly when click in cancel button without redirect to another url.
[image]
Thanks.
Rejo

(sorry for my english).

Comment: Okay, the image is a good help but do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: Ive reffer this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Probably not the best way. You could listen to the location/href of the popup and if it's redirecting to the new url (which you don't want it to redirect to) close it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <h3>Thank you!</h3>
  <a href="javascript:close();">Close this window</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    close();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You are facing this problem because Facebook automatically redirects you to your application's URL.

Please create a separate HTML page and copy/paste the above code, and supply the Facebook redirect URL with this: http://www.abcde.com/example.php

The popup window will be closed.